# Apache won't start on DirectAdmin server: Invalid command 'RMode'

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have a problem with my server's httpd service. When I try to start it, it returns the following error:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 28 of /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/dnsbeheer/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'RMode', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The server is running DirectAdmin Control Panel.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Grep the file for `RMode` figure out why that is broken, and fix it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that Apache doesn't understand the "RMode" command. This means that the module that implements it either wasn't included in your configs or failed to load. Search your configs for the module that provides RMode to make sure it's being loaded and if it's in a config other than httpd.conf, make sure it's being included by httpd.conf (like files in conf.d tend to be.)

Answer (score 1):

RMode is part of mod_ruid if you are using mod_ruid then make sure Apache is loading it. Depending on were you added the module to load then Direct Admin might have overwritten your changes when if it was told to rewrite the HTTP config.

If you are not using mod_ruid then you might need to check /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/dnsbeheer/httpd.conf for any config which is referring to mod_ruid looks like the following

```
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
            RMode config
            RUidGid user user
            RGroups apache access
    </IfModule>
```

if it doesn't then you will need to correct the virtual_host templates in /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates and rewrite the configs